# Single WMS from single mapfile with several rasters in MapServer

Tags: raster, layers, mapserver, openlayers-2, mapfile

I have several rasters in a single mapfile, I put them as layers like here:

```
LAYER
    NAME            "Layer 1"
    GROUP           "All Layers"
    TYPE            RASTER
    STATUS          ON
    DATA            "layer1.png"

    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END

    METADATA
        "wms_title"         "Layer 1"
        "wms_srs"           "EPSG:4326"
        "wms_group_title"   "All layers"
        "wms_abstract"          "No abstract"
        "wms_server_version"        "1.1.1"
        "wms_format"            "image/png"
        "wms_include_items"     "all"
        "gml_include_items"     "all"
        "gml_geom_type"         "raster"
    END
END

LAYER
    NAME            "Layer 2"
    GROUP           "All Layers"
    TYPE            RASTER
    STATUS          ON
    DATA            "layer2.png"

    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END

    METADATA
        "wms_title"         "Layer 2"
        "wms_srs"           "EPSG:4326"
        "wms_group_title"   "All layers"
        "wms_abstract"          "No abstract"
        "wms_server_version"        "1.1.1"
        "wms_format"            "image/png"
        "wms_include_items"     "all"
        "gml_include_items"     "all"
        "gml_geom_type"         "raster"
    END
END

LAYER
    NAME            "Layer 3"
    GROUP           "All Layers"
    TYPE            RASTER
    STATUS          ON
    DATA            "layer3.png"

    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:4326"
    END

    METADATA
        "wms_title"         "Layer 3"
        "wms_srs"           "EPSG:4326"
        "wms_group_title"   "All layers"
        "wms_abstract"          "No abstract"
        "wms_server_version"        "1.1.1"
        "wms_format"            "image/png"
        "wms_include_items"     "all"
        "gml_include_items"     "all"
        "gml_geom_type"         "raster"
    END
END
```

The problem is that I want to have a single WMS layer (named as in GroupTitle) as output from this mapfile (because it is only one mapfile), instead I have four WMS layers (three coming from each LAYER and one from the GROUP LAYER).

How can I achieve what I want? I use Mapserver 6.4.1 in OL 2.11.

Answer (score 4):

I am in a similar situation. I don´t need to hide or show the different rasters **separately**. If that's OK for you, this is what I did:

As far as I know, in the *mapfile - Layer - Data* you can only specify one file, but you can create several **identical** layers with the very same name, each one of them pointing to a different raster. Loading this WMS layer shows all the rasters at a time.